# Checking for equations used in ArcGIS field calculations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I was using the field calculation to seek some information. I closed my table of attributes and reopened it and wanted to verify that I had used the right equation for my field statistics. Although the correct information was still in the table, I wasn't able to see the equation I had used. Is there a way for me to retrieve or find the equation?

I'm using ArcMap Desktop, Version 10.2.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Click geoprocessing and choose result.
2. Open result processing and find the calculate field sorted by date (by default).
3. Double-click on "Calculate Field" to view the code used for specific field calculation.

Comment: I have the same question for QGIS 3.10.o A Coruna. Is there a possibility to verify which equations were used in the field caluclator?

Comment: Hi, there is a similar option in processing\history, but seems like it does not consider the field calculation as a processing. Im not sure if this option exist or you can try by opening new thread in forum cos mostly i use esri.